# Mongoose model access to schema properties

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema

```
import * as mongoose from "mongoose";

let _posteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ...
  updatedAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
  ...
});

export default (_posteSchema);
```

And in an other file i'm trying this

```
import * as mongoose from "mongoose";
import posteSchema from "./poste-schema";

let Poste = mongoose.model("Poste", posteSchema);
let _poste = new Poste();
_poste.updatedAt = Date.now();
```

I got the error "TS2339:Property 'updatedAt' does not exist on type 'Document'.
It used to work, and i'm near crying on that...

Any help would be sooooo great ;)

(using "mongoose": "^4.11.12")

Answer (score 0):

Don't use @types packages ! (@types/mongoose and @types/passport-local-mongoose) break the mecanism